# How can I use console log in AMP and Mustache?

Tags: javascript, mustache, amp-html

I'm looking at the [AMP Specifications](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec) and unable to find any way to log local variables on console.

Trying to achieve auto suggest by following the example from [AMP Examples](https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/autosuggest/). Is there a way I can print either response from `apm-list` or print option item (set using `option="{{.}}"` in `amp-selector`) on console?

Comment: use console.log to check any response and error encountered. See [developer tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), for guides. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `#development=1` query parameter in your URL, you can use the `AMP.printState()` in the console to pretty-print status of the present state variables present.

You can find more about it [Here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#debugging-state)

---

*Edit: camelCase correction, as mentioned by @fabian-marz*

Comment: While this is theoretically true, the call is `AMP.printState()` (note the camelCase writing).

Answer (score 0):

add &development=1 to the URL. This will enable the console log file.

Comment: `&development=1` is for validating AMP page, this doesn't automatically start printing server response for `amp-list` or mustache rendering

Comment: Ah, okay, I was think it will it enable, too.

Answer (score 0):

Add #development=1 and AMP.printstate() will work